# [SOLVED]Python library (clipboard_monitor) continues processing the clipboard in a loop? Or my script needs to be refurnished?

Tags: python, image, url, copy-paste, monitor

I am developing a simple script to download images from specific domains when the desired URL of the image is copied to the clipboard. Before downloading the image I change some parts in the URL.
In order to monitor the clipboard and listen for some text containing the specified domains I use the library "clipboard_monitor". Unfortunately the result of running the script and copying to the clipboard a [link][1]

Instead the function running every time I copy something new, I got an infinite loop of using the "**def URL2FhdImage(url):**", which is getting called by the function "**clipboard_monitor.on_text(URL2FhdImage)**" which is getting triggered on update of clipboard? (I suppose, as far as I could understand the structure of the library itself)

The infinite loop looks like the following:

> Listen to the copied photo URLS from BoatAround or MMK...
>
> I just got the MMK link...
>
> ***Processing***
> I just saved the image from MMK...
>
> I just got the MMK link...
>
> ***Processing***
> I just saved the image from MMK...
>
> I just got the MMK link...
>
> ***Processing***
> I just saved the image from MMK...

What I am asking is this, is the library that needs to be fixed or I need to fix my script?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved. The problem was inside my code. The lib clipboard_monitor of course was alright !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).